# Display two items on first line and third item on the next line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to have two items on one line, then have a third item on the next line. I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26086594/4861207), but the answer didn't work for an `input type="text"`. The `input` is on its own line, which results in each element having its own line.

Why doesn't it work, and how can I have the first two elements on one line, and the third element on the second line?

#### Working JSFiddle

#### Not Working JSFiddle

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}
#wrapper > *:last-child {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(144, 248, 144);">
  <label id="first">First Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="second">
  <span id="third">Third Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is default border and padding on `input` element so you can fix this with `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#wrapper > * {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}
#wrapper > *:last-child {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color: rgb(144, 248, 144);">
  <label id="first">First Text</label>
  <input type="text" id="second">
  <span id="third">Third Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` breaks to the next line because it has a 2px border applied by the user agent stylesheet.

[image]

To keep the `input` on the first line you could specify:

```
input { border-width: 0; }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sdpvLhmf/1/)

OR

alter the CSS box model to make padding and borders part of the width declaration:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sdpvLhmf/2/)